# How to eliminate whitespace when scrolling [fixed sidebar]

Tags: html, css, angular

Let me first try to illustrate the problem

I have a webpage which contains a header and a sidenav. The sidenav is fixed in css, since I don't its content to move when scrolling.

When the page isn't scrolled down it works as intended, somewhat like this

[image]

However when I scroll i don't want whitespace on top of the sidenav. Currently when I scroll down the page, it looks somewhat like this

[image]

The intended behavior should be something like this

[image]

How do I go about this in css? Do I mess with the z-index of the elements? so the sidenav is behind the header when the page isn't scrolled? Or do I dynamically add to the sidenav's size when scrolling?

And how would either of these options be done in css?

Comment: Please include your code, and ideally make a snippet / demo (jsfiddle, codepen etc) for us to work with. Thanks

Comment: You could hide the sidebar under the nav, but this means you cannot have content at the top portion of the sidebar because it would be hidden when the page is at the top. If this is ok, that's probably your simplest solution

Comment: @Huangism How can that be done in css?

Comment: You need your sidebar position:fixed and full height, then your header position absolute with a higher z-index

Comment: @JonasPraem you should post a minimum example of your isue so we can solve it with the same sample of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, you have to set z-index of the header higher than the `sidenav`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.header {
  height: 100px;
  background: #000000;
  position: relative;
  z-index:999;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top:100px;
}

.content {
  height: 1000px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```